# "Generic" wrapper for MVC5 - Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a "generic" return value for my MVC5-Controllers which returns something like

```
{ Success: true, 
Item: {Id:1, Name:"Oink" },
Error:null,
Message:"Everything works fine"
}
```

I want to keep this structure even if an exception occures. So currently I use something like this in my controller:

```
try {
    var stuff=new Stuff();
    return ReturnSomeJson(stuff.GetStuff(),"Everything works fine", true, null);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ReturnSomeJson(null, "That went wrong!", false, ex);
}
```

So this is the return method:

```
protected ReturnSomeJson (object item, string message, bool success, exception ex) {
    // more stuff
    return Json (this);
}
```

As this is quite a generic Exception handling I would like to avoid writing this try-catch over and over again.

I already fell about [different Exception methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine) in MVC, but all these display an error message directly.

But I want to keep the "ActionResult" returnvalue when using a generic Error handling.

Comment: I'm confused here - do you want generic error handling for web api controller or for MVC controller ?

Comment: Can't you just implement your try-catch inside `ReturnSomeJson`?

Comment: I use the `ControllerBase.OnException` method (#2) from your linked CodeProject. It works fine here, and it can return an `ActionResult`, just as you want.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I use a webapi inside mvc5. I clearified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to write the Try Catch statement in every controller action, you can create your own Exception Handler. By overriding the `OnException` method of `HandleErrorAttribute`.

You won't have to add the `try{}catch()` to every Action now, because when an Exception occurs it will call the `OnException`of the `ExceptionHandlerAttribute`

I have one which looks like this:

```
public class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private static readonly string[] DefinedException = { "SessionTimeOutException", "UnauthorizedAccessException" };
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            return;

        var validationContainer = new ValidationContainer();
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var exceptionName = filterContext.Exception.GetType().Name;
        string exceptionMessage;
        if (DefinedException.Contains(exceptionName))
        {
            exceptionMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            exceptionMessage = "We intentionally allowed to not catch exception to track the root causes. Please note down the steps and include following details in the bug.</br>"
                               + "</br></br>Exception Message: " + filterContext.Exception;
        }
        validationContainer.AddMessage(MessageType.Error, exceptionMessage);

        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = validationContainer,
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

I am adding the ValidationContainer class here, (because it is used above)

```
public class ValidationContainer
{
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }
    public List<string> SuccessMessages { get; set; }
    public List<string> WarningMessages { get; set; }
    public List<string> InformationMessages { get; set; }

    public void AddMessage(MessageType messageType, string message)
    {
        switch (messageType)
        {
            case MessageType.Information:
                InformationMessages.Add(message);
                break;
            case MessageType.Success:
                SuccessMessages.Add(message);
                break;
            case MessageType.Error:
                ErrorMessages.Add(message);
                break;
            case MessageType.Warning:
                WarningMessages.Add(message);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum MessageType
{
    Error = 1,
    Success = 2,
    Warning = 3,
    Information = 4,
    Debug = 5,
}
```

Then you can use it in the Controller:

```
[ExceptionHandler]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

}
```

Or on an Action

```
    [ExceptionHandler]
    public ActionResult index()
    {
        return Json();
    }
```

Comment: `private static readonly string[] DefinedException = { "SessionTimeOutException", "UnauthorizedAccessException" };`
why? Exception can be related to anything.

Comment: @Manoz This helps us handle the message differently on the client side. Because our client side is Javascript - as we handlle SessionTimeOutException and UnauthorizedAccessException differently on the client e.g. for SessionTinOutException we redirect to login page

Comment: don't get you.  Because the end results is Json that will be returned to client . My question is why did you specify for those particular exception types- `SessionTimeOutException` and `UnauthorizedAccessException` 
Do we need to specify these kind of exceptions separately? aren't these handled automatically?

Comment: No you don't have to specify them separately. This will handle all expceptions.

Comment: @Manoz for SessionTimeOutException and UnauthorizedAccessException it will only add the exception message name instead of the HTML string

Comment: Fine with me. I can get the part thats useful for me and just ignore everything, which was specific to your project, @DawoodAwan

Comment: @DawoodAwan, That's great. Sorry to bother you once again. Why it just don't add message instead of name?
I wonder, these are application level exception and this behavior you were telling is weird to me.

Comment: @Manoz for the 2 defined exceptions, we only need Name on the Client side. Because if session Time out takes place we redirect to Login Page, and if UnAuthorisedAccress we display a message dialog "You do not have permission perform this action." So we only need the exception name to perform these actions. It's easier to compare with name in the JavaScript client

Comment: For users of this approach - here's an important note: this will catch ONLY the exceptions that happen WITHIN your actions and views. It won't catch ANYTHING outside that. For example, if someone enters and invalid URL which cannot be mapped to one of your controllers (or perhaps you made a mistake in your routing configuration) -- that will still result in the good old ASP.NET yellow error page.

Answer (score 4):

I've studied the exception handling question quite a bit and my conclusion is that the best place to put your generic error handler is in global.asax.cs, `Application_Error` method. Also, disable ALL other error handling that you can find (including MVC's handling), because that can catch and swallow an exception without you knowing.

I chose `Application_Error` because it's the absolute final handler. If that doesn't catch a rogue exception (which wasn't swallowed), then nothing will. If you use, for example, MVCs error handling, then there are still some errors that can be missed - like an exception in `Application_BeginRequest` or a missing controller, or a DLL loading exception or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I use it by this way

```
public abstract class ApiResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// is success
    /// </summary>
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// I think you want use a error code here
    /// </summary>
    public string Error{get;set;}

    /// <summary>
    /// message
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// error 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ApiResult Error(string message)
    {
        return new ErrorApiResult(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Success
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ApiResult<T> Success<T>(T data)
    {
        return new ApiResult<T>()
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = null,
            Data = data
        };
    }

}
public class ErrorApiResult:ApiResult {
    public ErrorApiResult(string errorCode,string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        Success = false;
        Error = errorCode;
    }
}
public class ApiResult<T>: ApiResult
{

    /// <summary>
    /// the success return data
    /// </summary>
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public static ApiResult<T> Error(string message)
    {
        return new ApiResult<T>() {Message = message, Success = true};
    }
    public static ApiResult<T> Error(bool isSuccess,string message)
    {
        return new ApiResult<T>() {Message = message, Success =isSuccess};
    }
}
```

And you can use it in your method:

```
... ReturnSomeJson (object item, string message, bool success, exception ex) {
    if(success){
       return Json(new ApiResult.....)
    }
    // more stuff
    return Json (this);
}
```

But I think difference method is better:

```
ActionResult Error(string error,string message,Exception ex){
    var json = new ErrorApiResult(error,message);
    return Json(json);
}
ActionResult Success<T>(T data,string message=null){
    var json = ApiResult<T>.Success(data);
    return Json(json);
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC you can use filter to catch all exceptions in action:

```
  protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);
        filterContext.Result = Json(new ErrorApiResult("error", filterContext.Exception.Message));
    }
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong here. I do not search for an error-return-function but to find a way to return something on ANY exception that occurs anywhere

Comment: I also don't get how this is related to error handling

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood, if you want to deal with exceptions in MVC, you can use the Filter,you can write a ActionFilter class or override OnException method in your Controller/BaseController .

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification (for others having the same issue) I want to "clean" Dawood Awans answer which helped in my case but had "too much" real-world code in it that isn't needed for this topic and also missed one crucial command, my solution I finally used here:

```
 public class JsonExceptionAttribute:HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            // We alread dealt with it
            return;
        }
        var jsonRet = new JsonReturn();
        filterContext.Result = 
          MyCustomJsonException(filterContext.Exception); // This is my custom method returning a JSON-String
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Without the last command this ASP/MVC still throws the error